# Solving a system of equations with as many unknown and known variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following four variables for each $j=1,\ldots,J$ and $J>1$:

$\theta_{j}\in\mathbb{R}$,

$\tilde{\theta}_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{j}\theta_{i}$,

$a_{j}\in\mathbb{R}$,

$\tilde{a}_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{j}a_{i}$,

Assume that all $\theta_{j},\tilde{\theta}_{j}$ are unobserved, while all $a_{j},\tilde{a}_{j}$ are observed.

Further, assume a model in which we restrict
\begin{align}
\frac{\theta_{j}}{a_{j}} &=\frac{\theta_{k}}{a_{k}},\quad\forall j,k, \\
\frac{\theta_{j}}{a_{j}} &=\frac{\tilde{\theta}_{k}}{\tilde{a}_{k}},\quad\forall j\leq k
\end{align}

(1) Would it be possible to solve the model for $\theta_{j}$ in terms of only $a_j$'s?

(2) If this is not possible, what kind of other restrictions would I need to place on the model? I have some freedom on placing restrictions on the $a_j$'s, but not on the $\theta_j$'s.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say $$\tilde{\theta}_{j'} = \sum_{i=1}^{j}\theta_{i}$$ I have a feeling this is a typo of some sort.  Perhaps the subscript $j'$ should be $j$?  (so that it's not a restriction but rather just restating your definition)  Also, on a notational issue, is there a reason you're using $j'$ as a subscript and not, for instance, $k$?

Comment: I'd like to see a clearer set up of your problem.  It sounds like the $\theta_j$ are "unknowns" and the $\alpha_j$ are "knowns.  The tilde versions of these variables seem to be just derived from those by summations, so they don't contribute anything to the model or its solution (as far as I can tell; see @Brian's comment).  For simplicity, take $J=1$.  You know $\alpha_1$, but it doesn't seem to determine $\theta_1$ (am I missing something?).

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thank you for your comment! The $j'$ was a typo and should be $j$, and I've corrected this now. I was just restating the definitions, but I've deleted this now to clarify the problem. Also, I've changed notation from $j'$ to $k$.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, all $\theta_j$ are unknowns while $a_j$ are knowns. You're right, $J=1$ will not work. I've updated notation such that $J>1$. On your second point, you have a point that the summations are not contributing with new information. What sort of restrictions could I impose on $a_j$ to make this solvable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarifying comments on the Question, we can clear away some of the obscuring notation and direct attention to the central restrictions and the total set of solutions.  From this we find that the solutions have a single degree of freedom, so that one additional condition on the $\theta_i$ collectively suffices to determine them, given nonzero values of $\alpha_i$.

The assumption that $\alpha_i \neq 0$ is needed to make sense of the indicated divisions:

$$ \frac{\theta_j}{\alpha_j} = \frac{\theta_k}{\alpha_k}  \;\; \forall j,k $$

Similarly for the indicated division of the tilde (summation) variables, we ought to require the running sums $\tilde\alpha_k \neq 0$.  Such a condition would be automatically satisfied if it were known the $\alpha_j \gt 0$, but that is not stated in the Question (so presumably negative $\alpha_j$ are possible).

One would say that the equations above tell us there is a (real) constant of proportionality between the $\theta_j$ and $\alpha_j$ terms.  Taking that unknown constant to be $r\in \mathbb R$, all model solutions have the form:

$$ \theta_j = r \alpha_j $$

It follows that $\tilde\theta_k = \sum_{j=1}^k \theta_j$ would bear the same relationship to the $\tilde\alpha_k = \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j$, namely:

$$ \frac{\tilde\theta_k}{\tilde\alpha_k} = r \;\; \forall k $$

Thus the additional ratio conditions are satisfied.

In summary there is only a parameter $r$ that needs to be determined in order to find $\theta_j$ given $\alpha_j$, and that parameter can be any real number.  If not know directly, the value $r$ could be derived from any single value of $\theta_j$ or from a value of one of the running sums $\tilde\theta_k$.

There are additional ways one might impose an extra condition, and it should be left to the problem's poser to suggest what is most naturally imposed.

Comment: Yes, $a_j<0$ is possible. In my problem, it is natural to pose restrictions on the sum of $a_j$'s, something like $\tilde{a}_j=c$, where $c$ is a constant. Would that kind of restrictions help to solve for $\theta_j$?

Comment: No, that would not help because you already know all the values $\alpha_j$, and thus any sum of a subset of them is known.